# Fake nominal capacity of 18650 batteries?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have bought, from different sellers,  two 18650 batteries, but it seems that the capacity is much lower than the 4500 mAh or 3000 mAh label.

In real life, it seems to be able to draw a constant 500 mA during 1.2 hours, not more.

[image]

I have charged them with a [TP4056 module](http://www.ebay.fr/itm/261704276658?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) that seems to have good reviews on the internet.

**Are there some tricks to be able to use 18650 at their best?**

**Or is just that the  ebay UltraFire 18650 batteries I purchased were really bad?**

(*If so, what would be better manufacturers? I would understand if product recommandation might be off topic, if so, do you have ideas of places that analyze this subject?*)

Comment: You cannot get more than about 2800mAh of capacity in a Li-ion 18650. Anyone else offering much more is running a scam.

Comment: Ok @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. If one of you can recommand a seller / brand that sells 18650 batteries *not lying* about capacity with a factor x 10, thanks a lot in advance, it would save me days of trials and errors (and of poor experience with fake batteries)

Comment: I suggest you buy Panasonic 18650 batteries. Several companies buy them, add a protection circuit (a good idea) and then resell them under their own brand. Check the candlepower forums for specific test results and recommendations. "Vapers" also use 18650's extensively. But I think the candlepower forums are more rigorous, engineering wise.

Comment: By the way, I think 2800 might be a little low. Panasonic is selling 3400 mAh batteries, and I don't think Panasonic is running a scam.

Comment: I would trust Panasonic to eke out a bit more than the common value. I would not trust *anyone* to be able to add 50%.

Comment: I wonder how you can be sure that whatever is under the new shrink wrap (for the protected cell) is actually a genuine Panasonic or whatever name-brand cell. The actual manufacturers are loath to sell unprotected cells to other than battery pack makers, for good reason.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Sorry I probably didn't understand, can you explain more (protected / unprotected / shrink wrap), I don't know much about these batteries...

Comment: Word on the flashlight sites is that batteries w/ "Fire" in the name are generally to be avoided.  There are reliable companies out there that add protection circuits to brand new Panasonic 18650's.  It's a great idea to use such batteries if your device doesn't handle all aspects of monitoring and charging, as Li Ions that are overdischarged have a propensity to vent with fire when you charge them.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I trust orbtronic due to good reputation. They specify the exact model number of Panasonic battery they are using. They COULD be misleading us, I guess, but they have been around and not gotten busted yet. Eagletac seems to be a good brand also, but I am not sure if they are using panasonic cells. They do say made in Japan, and they are 3400 mAh (some models are).

Comment: Ask the sellers.  I had sellers reply from "About 10% of rated capacity sounds about right" to "If you do not get its capacity out of it, it's money back."

Comment: @ Ignacio and  mkeith. You are both correct. Most of the cell in-use today are 2200 to 2800mAh, but indeed you can now find some above 3000 (LG, Samsung and the well known Panasonic 3400 mAh). The biggest secret: you can tell most fakes by weight. They are way lighter than the average 45g or original cells.

Answer (score 3):

I wish I could post images in comments, but since I can't, I made this answer a wiki.  Anyway:

[image]

(from Google Images, "counterfeit capacitor")

Comment: Oh oh! Interesting, indeed!

Comment: I had a problem with some transistors (this was in mass production). After investigation, I found out that the CM bought them from a non-approved (but well-known and respected) distributor in Hong Kong. Manufacturer of the transistors would not touch them since they were not bought through authorized distribution. So we had one disassembled at a lab. Get this. There were no bonding wires between the die and the legs on the SOT-23 package. They were either test rejects scavenged from garbage or completely fake.

Comment: I was on a satellite program which procured a bunch of ceramic-bodied, mil-spec, high-rel voltage regulators. It turned out that in the package was an LM309 chip.

Comment: You can't add images in comments but you can add links to images using by surrounding the link word with square brackets and following it with the link itself in round brackets, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6V5R2.jpg)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Okay, but I also noticed that adding an image to an answer also transfers it to SE's server.  (the link changes and still works)  Can I still do that in a comment, in case the original goes away?

Comment: You can upload it to imgur where the images seem to be kept, and link to that, but beyond that I'm not sure what happens- beyond what I've investigated to date.

Answer (score 2):

To add to this, from a comment from @Bob very recently:

[image]

[image]

I have some black shrink wrap ones that are basically half empty. The capacity is much, much less than marked amount. On the plus side, they do appear to have short-circuit (only) protection so they'll just swindle you, not try that hard to kill you.

Arguably the ones in the photos are relatively safe. Much less dangerous materials in them, and they're 'double-hulled'. Of course an inert cylinder of clay would be even safer.

Comment: Wow, interesting again! Where to find safe/non-fake ones then?

Comment: Right now it seems a bit like finding safe bathtub gin was during Prohibition. Try to deal with those of good reputation and with some recourse if your semi-contraband isn't up to snuff.

Comment: I think you are safe with Orbtronic or Fenix brand batteries. Maybe Eagletac, too. These brands are all a little bit hokey sounding, but they have been around for at least a few years and seem to be reliable. I have several fenix LED flashlights (torches to those in the UK), and they are great.

Comment: I have (have had for a couple years) one of those batteries too... wish I would have seen this breakdown in time to do a chargeback.  Only one thing is going to make the fakes stop, and that's hurting their income stream.

Comment: The author should read this: https://xaeus.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/how-to-identify-18650-cell-capacity/